# Build JavaFX 8 with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, javafx-8

I tested to create JavaFX 8 project with Netbeans 7.4. But unfortunately with no luck. This is the POM file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dx57dc</groupId>
    <artifactId>JFX8M</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>JFX8M</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.dx57dc.jfx8m.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I compile the jar file run it with Netbeans 7.3.1 I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (unpack-dependencies) on project JFX8M: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\..\bin\javafxpackager" (in directory "D:\Documents and Settings\pterzie\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JFX8M"): CreateProcess error=14001, This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem -> [Help 1]
```

When I compile the project and run it on Netbeans 7.4 I get this error stack:

```
Executing command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\..\bin\javafxpackager -createjar -nocss2bin -appclass com.dx57dc.jfx8m.MainApp -srcdir D:\Documents and Settings\pterzie\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JFX8M\target/classes -outdir D:\Documents and Settings\pterzie\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JFX8M\target -outfile JFX8M-1.0.jar
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.782s
Finished at: Sat Aug 03 13:25:30 PDT 2013
Final Memory: 14M/34M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (unpack-dependencies) on project JFX8M: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\..\bin\javafxpackager" (in directory "D:\Documents and Settings\pterzie\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JFX8M"): CreateProcess error=14001, This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (unpack-dependencies) on project JFX8M: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\..\bin\javafxpackager" (in directory "D:\Documents and Settings\pterzie\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JFX8M"): CreateProcess error=14001, This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1043)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:319)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=14001, This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1024)
    ... 28 more
```

Is there any example with Java 8 and Maven which is implemented and working properly?

***P.S***
I managed to make it working after I remove a plugin. I edited the POM this way:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dx57dc</groupId>
    <artifactId>JFX8M</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>JFX8M</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass></mainClass>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.dx57dc.jfx8m.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

It works only for JVM 8. Am I missing something important into the POM file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**JavaFx 8 do work and will only work with Java 8.**

Also check the current javaFx roadmap: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html

I did not have any problems getting it running.

1. Download and install JDK8: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html
   1.1. be sure it's the oonly one and default jdk on your system if you don't know what you are doing ...
2. Download Netbeans 7.4: https://netbeans.org/downloads
3. In Netbeans: (File -> New project -> Project from Archetype -> "type in under javafx" -> "select": javafx-basic-archetype)
   3.1. don't forget to set the organisation name
4. Download &/ copy paste an javaFx 8 class example &/ demo from somewhere, for example: http://carlfx.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/introduction-by-example-javafx-8-printing/
   4.1. Now set the project sources to 1.8 and utf-8
5. Clean and build and run it!
6. enjoy!

In case your are having troubles in finding the javafx-8-libs with maven from the console or with  another ide, than you have to set the javafx-8-lib-path like this:

1. You have to tell maven where the javafx-lib is exactly:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.1</version>
       <configuration>
               <!-- this maven plugin does not functions with java 8 yet, passing java 7 is just fine. -->
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
           <compilerArguments>
               <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
           </compilerArguments>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

** Note: you don't have to use that specific archetype mentioned above to get it running
** Nothing really bad, but next time just paste the delta of your content instead of posting all of it again, without the delta the effort is much higher, since a comparison of the file have to be made by each one trying to understand it ...