# JavaFX maven plugin: Failed to execute goal

Tags: java, maven, javafx-8

I created a new JavaFX maven project using Netbeans IDE v.8.1. I then copy-pasted `javafx-maven-plugin` definition from [the plugin's official GitHub site](http://javafx-maven-plugin.github.io/)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.chat.test.MainApp</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-jfxjar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is when I run the test project I get the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project test: The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

I have pushed the test project to a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/yunus89/javafx-maven-plugin-test.git), which you can clone and run.

Comment: Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031931/build-javafx-8-with-maven?

Comment: shouldnt your goal be just 'jar'

Comment: @kuhajeyan, i copy-paste exactly what the javafx-maven-plugin official site provided. It works when i use javafx with springboot.

Comment: @Tunaki, i have not been able to see anything helpful. Isn't the plugin enough to run run a simple project like that?

Comment: @Tunaki, i used the archetype which was suggested in the link you provided (javafx-basic-archetype), and it works. Nice.

Comment: Please update to the current version of the plugin: 8.5.0 (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that maven-plugin, and yes, the website is heavily outdated)

Comment: @FibreFoX, even when i updated test project(link on question) to 8.5.0, still when i run it throws the same error